# Database referencing tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hi I'm trying to do some database stuff and having done anything for ages I tried to search but I don't think I'm using the right words.

I have two tables

Person(Num_PK, name, phone)
Titles(Num_PK, title)

titles is a pre filled table that has content like Mr, Mrs, etc

My question is does person need a foreign key to this title that holds title num?
or do I need to create another table has both the num_pk's in it bit like a joiner?
A bit like in the image which I cant post.

Person(Num_PK, name, phone) - 
Joiner(Num_PK"person", Num_PK"title") 
- titles(Num_PK, title)

Comment: Please stop writing and saying "basically" - it's a high tech "um".

Comment: How is that help full duffymo?

Comment: If one person can have only one title then you dont need a joiner(your word). Keep references on person table. If a person can have multiple titles then you should have a joiner.

Comment: It's very helpful if it helps you sound less ignorant.

Comment: Not true, Serif Emek.  You can still have a foreign key even if only one title is allowed.  It's called "normalization".

Comment: So it person will need title_FK which holds the matching number.

Comment: Please try to understand first, duffymo. What a reference can mean in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no perfect answer here.

You would add a foreign key in the PERSON table to TITLE if strict 3rd normal form mattered to you.  You would avoid repeating titles for every person; only values that you added would be allowed.

Denormalization is allowed, of course.  If you'd rather make that column hold the title value you can do it.  You just repeat values and can't restrict to the set of your choice.

Know the rules; understand the consequences.  You can choose to break rules like "always normalize to the greatest extent possible" as long as you understand the ramifications.

Comment: 3rd normal form are the words.

Comment: Cool thx's so foregin key if one, otherwise its a junction table if its many. I wasn't sure about the junction table thx's.